# Is there a nicer way to write "a == b ? c : a"?

Tags: javascript, java

This is something I use every now and then, where I want to evaluate as something different for some specific case, but otherwise evaluate as the original value. Sometimes the variable name of "a" can be something long, so it feels redundant to write it twice, so I wonder if there's a nicer way to write it. One example would be something like `longVariableName > 100 ? "big" : longVariableName`.

This also comes up when "a" is a function call, and you don't want to call the function twice, but don't want to save the return value to a variable either. Is that possible?

Comment: Javascript != Java 
:D

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What do you mean? You can use the ternary operator in any expression you like, whether or not it does an assignment.

Comment: The conditional operator is probably preferable here, *because* it evaluates to an expression conditionally. `if`/`else` would be more verbose. @OP, I think your code is fine, don't be afraid of declaring a variable to make it cleaner

Comment: @EddieD The ternary operator happens to exist in both, and I use it in both. Edit: Although now I do wonder if it causes confusion that I tagged two languages.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense as Java.  A conditional expression cannot evaluate to a `String` or an `int`.  Note the answer for Java and Javascript is likely to be different, so tagging your question with both makes this Too Broad.

Comment: @StephenC I used it in a println call

Comment: Also "nicer" is subjective, so that makes this question "asks for opinion" which is off topic.  If you want to get anything useful out of the Question: 1) pick ONE language, 2) use real (syntactically valid / meaningful) examples (more than one), and 3) state objective criteria rather than "niceness".

Comment: `I used it in a println call` In that case, the `int` probably got boxed to an `Integer`, and the type of the ternary operator evaluated to `Object`.  Which produces a correct result, but is a little expensive.

Comment: *"a little expensive"* ... and not generally applicable.  If you want a general answer (as indicated by your title) you need a sufficient breadth of (complete) examples so that we can talk about alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

> This also comes up when "a" is a function call, and you don't want to call the function twice, but don't want to save the return value to a variable either. Is that possible?

You are starting to think about functional programming. These kinds of problems are solved by lifting to another context.

Memoization is one technique, or using functions to cache the outcome of a() in a closure. As long as `a()` is a pure function and always returns the same value (so not calling the system time...), you can write your own helper functions to do it.

Here is a minimal example of your problem:

```
const a = () => 5
const d = 5
const default = 6
const c = a() == d ? a() : default
```

So you want to avoid calling `a()` twice. You could do this:

```
const a = () => 5

const equalsOrDefault = val => compared => default => val == compared ? val : default

const c = equalsOrDefault(a())(d)(6)
```

That function takes the value, what to compare it with, and a default. It evaluates it exactly once, and you have a ternary with the desired effect.

Comment: But we still need to use `val == compared ? val : default`, right? And that is what he is asking :P

Comment: He is also asking about not evaluating `a()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could specify a lambda, but it depends on how many times you want to use it as to whether it is worthwhile.  The point is, the `prod` method is only called once per use.

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface TrinaryOperator<T> {
        T apply(T a, T b, T c);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrinaryOperator<Integer> decide = (a,b,c)-> a.equals(b) ? c : a;

        int v = decide.apply(prod(20,30), 600, 10);
        System.out.println(v);
        v = decide.apply(prod(20,30), 700, 10);
        System.out.println(v);
    }


     static int prod(int n, int s) {
         return n * s;
    }
```